# How to fetch ${wlp.server.name} in log4j2.properties when we are using websphere liberty profile

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

My application is using websphere liberty profile(wlp) as server and my application is springboot application. I have a bootstrap file like below:
Server_log_filepath=/somepath/${wlp.server.name}
application_log_filename=${wlp.server.name}

Now suppose my ${wlp.server.name} actual value is MYWLPSERVER, So the thing is server logs are getting generated at the path /somepath/MYWLPSERVER correctly. But when i am trying to fetch application_log_filename in my log4j2.properties it's not working and my application logs are getting generated with name as ${wlp.server.name}.log instead of MYWLPSERVER.log
What I am doing in my log4j2.properties file is trying to read the value like below

appender.rolling.fileName={application_log_filename}

or

appender.rolling.fileName={env:application_log_filename}

Neither way it is picking the value from bootstrap.properties file.

Is there any way to fetch the value from. Bootstrap properties or server.env file to my log4j2 file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `wlp.server.name` is a Java system property, you should use `${sys:wlp.server.name}` instead.

Comment: Thanks @piotr , it worked by adding sys instead of env.  .. 